# C# Streamwriter enabling by button

Tags: c#, button, streamwriter

I would like to create application in which I could create file, write something into it by button clicking and then close this file by clicking another button. The problem is that when I've declared Streamwrtier object within one button I couldn't invoke file close method from within second button because I've got such error: *the name 'file' does not exist in the current context*. When I initiate Streamwriter outside the button method problem dissapeares but then file is being created before I will click button. Do you know how could I overcome this issue?

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = true;
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
        file.WriteLine(value.ToString());

    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = false;
        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The problem as presented is that the variable `file` is not ["in scope"](https://www.rusoaica.com/functions/variable-scope/) in the `button2_Click` method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic fix:

```
private StreamWriter file = null;
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Visible = false;
    button2.Visible = true;
    if (file == null)
        file = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
    file.WriteLine(value.ToString());
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Visible = true;
    button2.Visible = false;
    if (file is object) 
        file.Close();
}
```

But really, it's poor practice in most cases to hold the file open. You generally want something more like this, which handles opening and closing the necessary streams all in one go, and only keeps the file open for the minimum necessary duration:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.AppendAllText("test.txt", value.ToString());
}
```

And since we always close the file right away, the second button isn't needed at all.

Comment: `if (file is object)` is an interesting check, can you explain how that checks if the stream is open/needs to be closed?

Comment: @RonBeyer It's just a better "modern" replacement for the traditional naive `!= null` test. I picked it up from [Jared Parsons](https://twitter.com/jaredpar), who is on the C# language team at Microsoft. Really, this should be handled via `IDisposable` or the my second snippet, but baby steps.

Comment: Is it better than `file?.Close()` for some reason?

Comment: That would probably be fine, too. I don't have the exact way the `?.` operator expands, but I believe Jared prefers `is object` because of issues such as (but not limited to) overloading of the `!=` operator.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation!